# Cooling steel by putting it in water ; what is the final temperature

Tags: steel, temperature, homework

Below is a problem I made up and did. I am hoping that you will tell me that my solution is right.

Problem:

A $5$g piece of steel at $30$°C is placed in $400$ ml of water at
$20$°C. Assume that all the excess heat from the steel goes into the
water. What is the final temperature of the water?
Answer:

Using the Internet we find that the heat capacity of steel is $0.420$ J per gram.
Let $t_f$ be the final temperature of the water. It is also the final
temperature of the steel.
\begin{align*} 
5(0.42)(30-t_f) &= 400(1)(t_f - 20) \\
(0.42)(30-t_f) &= 80(t_f - 20) =  80t_f - 1600\\
0.42(30) - 0.42t_f &= 80t_f - 1600\\
12.6 - 0.42t_f &= 80t_f - 1600\\
12.6 &= 80.42t_f - 1600\\
t_f &= 20.05
\end{align*}
Hence the final temperature is $20.05$°C.

Is my solution right? It seems to low to me.

Comment: @jsotola You are right there was a problem with the  title on the post. I have updated the title.

Comment: why would it seem too low? ... you have 5 g of steel and 400 g of water

Comment: @jsotola I think of hot steel as having a lot of energy. Is my answer right?

Comment: I do not know if the answer is correct, but from experience I would not expect the water to warm up much ... it's like taking a spoon from hot coffee and putting it in a glass of warm water ... the water would not warm up noticeably ... don't forget that you have only 5 g of warm metal, not hot metal and you are submerging in large amount of water that is only 10 degrees cooler

Comment: Yes you’re correct.

Comment: So consider the difference if the steel was at 300 dec C or 600 deg C. How do the results compare?

Comment: @SolarMike intuition tells me that the water would not heat up much even then

Comment: you dropped 5 marginally hotter paper clips into a large cup of water.  The temperature wont change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right. One thing you have to take into account is [heat capacity of the water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_heat_capacity) 4.184 J/(g K). With that, the equation will look like:

$$5\cdot 0.42\cdot (30-t_f) = 400\cdot 4.184\cdot (t_f-20)$$

So the final temperature $t_f$ is:

$$t_f = \frac{5\cdot 0.42\cdot 30 + 400\cdot 4.184\cdot 20}{5\cdot 0.42 + 400\cdot 4.184} \dot{=} 20.0125 °C$$

So as you can see, it is even lower due to much greater mass as well as thermal capacity of water.

Comment: I thought the heat capacity of water was 1.

Comment: I think your 4.186 should be 4.184 in the first equation.

Comment: You are right, I took it from 2 sources, 4.184 was at 20 °C, so I switched to that one and forgot to change it in the 1st equation. Why would you think heat capacity of water is 1?

Comment: I was thinking of the definition of a calorie.

Comment: When in doubt about these things, checking the units and doing simple dimensional analysis might help ;)